# DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged. with buttons interactions discord.js V14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I 'am getting this error in all my buttons
some times it do what in the code sometimes the errors come early

```
DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\ryuuo\Desktop\ryuu\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:659:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\ryuuo\Desktop\ryuu\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:458:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\ryuuo\Desktop\ryuu\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:902:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferReply (C:\Users\ryuuo\Desktop\ryuu\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:69:5)        
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\ryuuo\Desktop\ryuu\Buttons\languague.js:11:5) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 5, data: { flags: 64 } } },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1037980437043236884/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTAzNzk4MDQzNzA0MzIzNjg4NDpteWUxWkVidG8xY1VsUkpOU3Jxb3JJSnp2b2JwSlFtUUVqVnFEb0FNeEg4UUZqc1JNMWdyMkYxU3JNMDdPR2RDMEV2U3Q0TzByMkMzY1lQTk1kS09SVHh5SjEwR1daOHF6OVhWbEh0bDJYd1B6UFpIYXdMYktwczF3RXRxNVFFTA/callback'
}
```

I 'am using :
Discord.js Version 14.6.0
Node.js Version 18.11.0

I tried  with a simple reply like

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async(interaction) => {
    if(!interaction.isButton()) return;
    if(interaction.customId === "test")
    await interaction.reply({
      content: "Test worked",
      ephemeral: true
    });
  });
```

and getting the same error after the bot reply
I tried also with a buttons handler and same

Comment: Looks like you might have nested event listeners. Do you create a new listener every time the button is sent?

Comment: @MrMythical no i even removed all listener and started the bot the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it it seems that the problem was from the handler I edited the interaction filter from this

```
 if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand) return;
```

to this

```
 if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand || 
      interaction.isButton() ||
      interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;
```

and it works fine